# Are there any downsides to accidentally sudo composer require command

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

I accidentally entered:

```
sudo php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

and I read that I should not  run Composer as root/super user, particularly for install/update/exec.

My question is that is require another one of the commands that gives third parties execution abilities? I immediately deleted the instance afterwards, but i am afraid i have to change all my passwords if for some reason third parties can install scripts

I am on a bitnami linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Composer website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md):

> Certain Composer commands, including exec, install, and update allow third party code to execute on your system. This is from its "plugins" and "scripts" features. Plugins and scripts have full access to the user account which runs Composer. For this reason, it is strongly advised to avoid running Composer as super-user/root.

As you see, this advice is because when you grant root privileges (by preceding the command with `sudo`), the plugin or script that you are about to install, **has full access to the root account**! And this means if the plugin/script is a malware, then Rest in Peace ! ;-)

Particularly about your case, the `guzzle` library is a well known php library & is not intended to be a malware, **So don't worry, Nothing bad has happened to your system**. :-)

Comment: thank you. this definitely will save me a lot of time